# How to switch multiple react components on same page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a user dashboard build using material-ui list. For each listItem i have a component for it. What I want is, when I click a list element, there is a section dedicated for switching the components. I am having trouble implementing this.Here is my code.I am not sure where to put `onClick` handler. I will appreciate any lead. Even loggin when a particular listItem is clicked. Then I can go ahead and use react conditional rendering.
In the picture below, when a user clicks All events, a component for that is rendered on the right. When `MyEvents` is clicked, a component for it, is rendered.

[image]

Code:

`UserTileData.js`

```
export const profileFolderListItems = (
  <div>
    <ListItem button>
     <ListItemIcon>
       <SendIcon />
     </ListItemIcon>
     <Badge badgeContent={3} color='primary'>
       <ListItemText primary='Events attending' />
     </Badge>
     </ListItem>
     <ListItem button>
       <ListItemIcon>
        <CreateIcon />
       </ListItemIcon>
     <ListItemText primary='New Event' />
    </ListItem>

  </div>
)
```

`UserProfilePage.js`

```
 class UserProfile extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      componentTodisplay: null

    }
  }

  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props

    return (
      <div>

        <div className={classes.root}>

          <Drawer
            variant='permanent'
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper
            }}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <List >{eventsFolderListItems}</List>
            <Divider />
            <List>{profileFolderListItems}</List>
          </Drawer>
          <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            {/* componentToDisplay goes here */}

          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

UserProfile.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(UserProfile)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you actually mean by switching components? Do you want to conditional rendering? Or change the props?

Comment: @Abrar I have updated the question with a visual aid

Comment: How are you passing the list item names in `profileFolderListItems `? I mean the `primary` props, shouldn't it be dynamically rendered?

Comment: There is `UserTileData.js` with those info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use React Router (or any similar routing library).

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

> In the picture below, when a user clicks All events, a component for
>   that is rendered on the right. When MyEvents is clicked, a component
>   for it, is rendered.

It would probably also be helpful if the user can browse to `/my-events` and `/all-events`, or bookmark them. What about when the user presses the back/forward buttons in their browser?

Using a routing library solves all of these problems (and more!) *for* you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't thought of this in terms of user experience and Navigation. Also, I have seen something similar to what I want in one of the links you have provided. Great eye opener @thirtydot

Answer (score 2):

Added a couple of change to your code. Now it looks like this -

`UserTileData.js`

```
export class profileFolderListItems {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ListItem button>
         <ListItemIcon>
           <SendIcon />
         </ListItemIcon>
         <Badge badgeContent={3} color='primary'>
           {/* notice the onClick handler here */}
           <ListItemText primary='Events attending' onClick={() => this.props.onSelectChange('events')}
         </Badge>
         </ListItem>
         <ListItem button>
           <ListItemIcon>
            <CreateIcon />
           </ListItemIcon>
         <ListItemText primary='New Event' />
        </ListItem>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`UserProfile.js`

```
import { profileFolderListItems, eventsFolderListItems} from './UserTitleData';

class UserProfile extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: null
    };

    this.handleSelectOption = this.handleSelectOption.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelectOption(value) {
    this.setState({
        value: value
    });
  }

  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>

        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Drawer
            variant='permanent'
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper
            }}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />

          </Drawer>
          <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            {/* notice the conditional rendering here */}

            {this.state.value === 'events' ?
              (<List>
                <profileFolderListItems
                  onSelectChange={this.handleSelectOption}
                />
                </List>) : 
             this.state.value === 'profile' ?
               (
                 <List>
                   <profileFolderListItems
                     onSelectChange={this.handleSelectOption}
                   />
                 </List>
               ) : null}

          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Basically what I am doing here is -

- Pass the value from the `ListItemText` to the onClick handler. (it should be unique for each of the options. I am passing `events` here only)
- Lift the value to the parent component - `UserProfilePage`. (React's single source of truth, unless you are using Redux)
- Conditional rendering based on the value passed.

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will have a look at it then let you know. And yea, I got the idea.

Comment: It worked. Thanks Again. A follow up question, why do we use the empty brackets like this?  `{() => this.props.onSelectChange('events')}`

Comment: Glad to know that! I have used ES6's arrow function, the first brackets are empty since I am not passing any value as parameter. In case you want to pass a value you should pass it in the first parenthesis